# Windows 10 upgrade version 1511, 10586 acts like it installs but does not actually install

Tags: windows, windows-10-v1511

I have done a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro (XPS 15 9550), installed drivers etc. 
When I do Windows update it downloads and installs version 1511, 10586 with no real fanfare.

When I do Windows update it downloads and installs version 1511, 10586 with no real fanfare.

When I do Windows update it downloads and installs version 1511, 10586 with no real fanfare.

It's like Groundhog day. I do the install look at the installed updates. It does not appear listed.

Is there a way to make this work? There are no error messages. It appears to work but does not as it downloads and "install" the same update over and over.

Comment: I don't understand.  Windows 10 build `10586` is `Version 1511`.  Type 'winver" in a run dialog provide the build information it provides.  Sounds like you should just download the Version 1511 and install the update manually.

Comment: Build 10240 is listed. I was listing what was on the update page

Comment: [Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench) the current Version 1511 .ISO, mount it, then start the installation process and simply choose "upgrade now"   Optionally you can put it on a flash device if you want.  The fact the system keeps trying to install the update means its failing at some point.  If the installation is really "fresh" just format and install build 10586 instead.